# Не правильно считает координату в JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Выводит отрицательные вещественные значения. Пример: y = -1085.679012345679. Не пойму как с этого значения получить нужную координату. Знаю что Math.cos или Math.sin возвращает значение в радианах. Пробовал считать выражение с округленными переменными.

```js
'use strict'
const g = 9.8;
shoot.addEventListener('click', function() {
        var v0 = +document.getElementById("v0Speed").value;
        var a = +document.getElementById("aAngle").value;
        var x = 500; // расстояние
        var t = x / (v0 * Math.cos(a));
        var y = v0 * Math.sin(a) * t - ((g*t*t)/2);
        console.log(t);
        console.log(y);
});

// Составить код для игровой программы попадания
// снаряда в цель. Траектория снаряда, вылетающего из
// орудия под углом a с начальной скоростью v0,
// описывается выражением
```

Comment: "оно мне выдает координату y = -1085.274237489238" - Какое значение Вы ожидаете? Каковы входные данные?

Answer (score 1):

> Знаю что Math.cos или Math.sin возвращает значение в радианах.

Немножко наоборот - аргумент этих функций должен быть в радианах, а не в градусах, а возвращают они безразмерную величину в пределах `-1..1`

Так что при использовании градусов их нужно перевести  в радианы

```
var radians = a / 180 * Math.PI;
```

и использовать

```
Math.cos(radians)
Math.sin(radians)
```

Пример для

```
  v = 250 м/c и angle=45 (Pi/4)
  t = 500 / (250 * 0.707) = 2.828 
  y = 250 * 0.707 * 2.828 - 10/2*(2.828)^2 = 500 - 40 = 460 м
```

Comment: Да, это уже понял, считаю в радианах

Answer (score 0):

1) исправь строчку: вместо **v0 * +** нужно написать просто **v0 ***(без знака +).

```
var y = v0*Math.sin(a)*t - ((g*t*t)/2);
```

2) у - это твоя координата (физическая). Она может быть любой. Положительное значение говорит о том, что тело еще в воздухе, 0 - ударилось о землю (меньше нуля обычно не рассматривают). Если ты хочешь рисовать сам процесс полета, то стоит учесть, что на экране координаты "перевернуты" и ось ОУ идет сверху-вниз. 
Т.е., например, если по твоим расчетам получится, что у=200, то на экране точку нужно рисовать с координатой "высота экрана" -200.

Comment: функция toFixed() возвращает строковое значение + перед ним преобразует в числовое. Значения в большинстве случаев возвращает отрицательные и они громоздкие. Их переводить в метры что ли?

Comment: убери вообще toFixed на этом этапе - зачем обрезать число в середине вычислений? Какие у тебя исходные данные в задаче ?

Comment: Да уже убрал. Буду считать в радианах, оно мне выдает координату y = -1085.274237489238. Как это значение разобрать? Может формула времени не та?

Comment: Смотри, в функции нужно высчитывать две координаты: х и у, а время Т ты будешь изменять в цикле, добавляя по секунде (или меньше, если нужно). Сейчас у тебя получается, что ты ищешь ВРЕМЯ в конкретной координате Х, а потом хочешь узнать У в это время. Скорее всего, снаряд уже глубоко в земле, о чем тебе и говорит отрицательный У

Comment: т.е. ты жестко забил, что снаряд сейчас на расстоянии 500 метров от начальной точки, вряд ли это было дано в условии задачи

Comment: Это условное расстояние до цели. Нужно взять откуда-то t он был переделан с формулы x = v0 * cos(a) * t в x = x / (v0  * cos(a))

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87067/discussion-between-mr-green-and-misha-mickhailov).